# VSCODE not showing javascript fuction console.logs

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've just started learning JavaScript and I'm following some online tutorials, this is what the tutorial has on vscode:

```
function countdown() {
    console.log(5)
    console.log(4)
    console.log(3)
    console.log(2)
    console.log(1)
}

console.log(countdown)
```

and it works fine, but on mine it will not work, this is what it returns:

> [Running] node "c:\Users\jmont\OneDrive\dev_prog\javascript\index.js"
> [Function: countdown]
>
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 0.152 seconds

I have node.js installed, and I have code runner extension as well

Answer (score 0):

Call the function:

`console.log(countdown())`

Right now you are only passing a reference to the function.

Comment: That is strange as the guy on the video has exactly the same as I do and he gets 5,4,3,2,1,...!

Comment: i think ive worked it out, i called the function with countdown() , and it worked , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function by adding the parentheses in order for it to print what you want it to.

```
console.log(countdown())
```

this will give the desired output